# shiny-server: variable names are limited to 10000 bytes

Tags: r, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am getting error while running the code in shiny-server only. When I am running the same code from R console using runApp() function it is running well. See the error message below....

```
Warning: Error in assign: variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
Stack trace (innermost first):
    46: assign
    45: wrapFunctionLabel
    44: public_bind_env$initialize
    43: Observable$new
    42: reactive
    41: templateServer
    40: server [/home/shiny-apps/ACCPlantAnalysis/server.R#20]
     1: runApp
Error in assign(name, func, environment()) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

Line no 41 and 40 are written by me. but other lines are not written by me; call from any reference library. I don't know from which library.

Comment: could we have a look at your code?

Comment: The error is clear. Do you suspect you may have a very long variable name somewhere in your code? If so, try to fix it.

Comment: Not in my code.... the error was showing from some library. I have not used long variable name. My variable names are only 8-10 byte long. Also same code is running from R console. Why so?

Comment: I can show my code. how can I share my code? please....advice

Comment: Please see the url... you will get the error. http://stat-tools.zivanta-analytics.com/apps/ACCPlantAnalysis/

Comment: you can share the code here, in your question.
could you please share the line 20 of your server.R ?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response..... below is my code of line 20..
     templateServer(input,output,session,csvData)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I got solution. I wrote functions for every 'if' block and put all code of 'if' block inside the function. Then call the function. And the was problem solved.

```
SectoralLeverageRatio(){
...
...
}

if (selectedIndex=="Sectoral Leverage Ratio"){
  SectoralLeverageRatio()
}
```

The conclusion is... if your 'if' block is large enough and you got 'variable names are limited to 10000 bytes' error. Replace the code inside  the 'if' block with user defined function.

This is the problem of shiny-server; not the problem of 'R'. If you run your code from 'R' console using runApp(), you would not get any error. But if you run through(production environment) you might get an error.

Comment: I had the same problem when running app in RStudio and this approach also removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to `?name`, you have to respect the fact that:

> Names are limited to 10,000 bytes (and were to 256 bytes in versions of R before 2.13.0).

and the rule says in `?make.names`:

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the
>   reserved words.

Comment: But I have not written that code. That code was called from some of the library. If I do that mistake, then same error will show by R console also.

Answer (score 0):

after a day long research I am able to pinpoint the issue. I have a long if..else block in my code. There are 10 if block and every if block has at least 6-8 line of code. When I comment one 'if' block of code (randomly chosen) the code running fantastically.... below is my 'if' block of code...

```
  else if (selectedIndex=="Sectoral Leverage Ratio"){
        ## Calculated number of row of the matrix ##
        rowNum <- selectedMonth[2] - selectedMonth[1] + 1

        ## Filter data based on criteria ##
        filteredData <- subset(rawData,Year %in% selectedYear & Month %in% selectedMonth[1]:selectedMonth[2] & Plant %in% selectedPlant)

        LeverageTable <- filteredData[,c('sch1ExpLeverage','sch2ExpLeverage','sch3ExpLeverage','sch4ExpLeverage','sch5ExpLeverage','sch7ExpLeverage','sch10ExpLeverage','sch11ExpLeverage')]
        LeverageSum <- apply(LeverageTable,2,sum)

        ExpTable <- filteredData[,c('sch1Exp','sch2Exp','sch3Exp','sch4Exp','sch5Exp','sch7Exp','sch10Exp','sch11Exp')]
        ExpSum <- apply(ExpTable,2,sum)


        LeverageRatio <- as.matrix(LeverageSum / ExpSum)
        AvgLeverageRatio <- as.matrix((LeverageSum / ExpSum)/rowNum)

        LeverageRatioTable <- cbind(LeverageRatio,AvgLeverageRatio)
        colnames(LeverageRatioTable) <- c('Leverage Ratio','Avg.Leverage Ratio')


        LeverageRatioTable <- data.frame(Sector=c('Health & Sant.','Edn. & Voc.','Social Welfare','Envt. Sust.','Hrtg & Arts','Sports','Rural Dvpt.','Admin Cost'),LeverageRatioTable)

        as.data.frame(LeverageRatioTable)

  }
```

All other 'if' blocks are almost similar (with some difference in calculation).

This is the problem of shiny-server; not the problem of 'R' itself.

If anybody wants to examin my code; I can share the full code.