# Why does this error occur when manipulating datatable style in shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatable, bslib

I have not yet been able to create an example to reproduce this error. I am using DT v0.28, shiny v1.7.4, and bslib v0.4.2.9000.

This error appears when changing various aspects of the table: the way a column is added to the data frame being used by `datatable()` from `DF$newColumn = ...` to `tibble::add_column`, setting widths using `columnDefs` for 6 columns but not 5, and including `.on("mouseenter", function() { ...` in the callback when styling the export buttons.

Any suggestions to help me debug this?

```
Warning: Error in assign: variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
  43: assign
  42: wrapFunctionLabel
  41: bindEvent.Observer
  40: bindEvent
  39: %>%
  38: server [/Users/me/Documents/work/apps/interactive-volcano-plot/app.R#2535]
   1: runApp
Error in assign(name, func, environment()) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: the problem seems to be unrelated to `DT` and something to do with large `if` blocks. The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37161788/2184368) resolved the error. I'm curious if anyone knows what the underlying issue is.